# Way to calculate matrix inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've learnt a way to compute the inverse of a matrix at class (given it is nonsingular), that is something like this:
$$(A|I)\mathop{\longrightarrow}^{row\;ops}(I|A^{-1})$$
I didn't think much about it until I read that the following is also correct:
$$(A|B)\mathop{\longrightarrow}^{row\;ops}(I|A^{-1}B)$$
So why are they correct, why is this a logical thing to do to get matrix inverses? Or is it simply because matrix inverses are defined this way?

Comment: A single row operation is the result of multiplying on the left by a matrix.  Can you do it now with this hint?

Comment: @saulspatz You're talking about permutation matrices, right? But how do they relate to matrix inverses?

Comment: Not just permutation matrices.  Any row operation can be effected by a matrix multiplication.  The product of all these matrices is a matrix $M$, and since $MA=I$ we have $M+A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment of saulspatz, a row operation can be considered as a left multiplication by some other matrix. Consider
$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

1. Subtracting first row from the second 4 times is the same as multiplying by $R_1$:
   $$
   R_1A = \left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    -4 & 1 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
   \end{array}
   \right) = \left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & -3 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)
   $$
2. Multiplying the second row by $-1/3$ is the same as multiplying by $R_2$:
   $$
   R_2R_1A=\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
   \end{array}
   \right)\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & -3 \\
   \end{array}
   \right) = 
   \left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)
   $$
3. Subtracting second row from the first row 2 times is the same as multiplying by $R_3$:
   $$
   R_3R_2R_1A = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   = I.
   $$

Now we see that $(R_3R_2R_1)A = I$, so by the definition of inverse matrix $R_3R_2R_1=A^{-1}$. However, when we apply the same operation to the matrix $B$, we find out that:
$$
R_3R_2R_1B = (R_3R_2R_1)B=A^{-1}B
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, so whenever I'm performing elementary row operations on a matrix $A$, it would be the same as performing the same elementary row operations on the identity matrix then left multiply it to $A$?

Comment: Yes. This is how it works